# x64dbg is unable to find string references vs. Ollydbg

Tags: ollydbg, x64dbg, strings

I want to know how to find string references in x64dbg as Olly does : it finds every string references I need when I open Memory map window, then rightclick on "Search" and then I enter the word I wanna search.

How to get the same result with x64dbg ? I'm sure it is possible but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I finally accidentally found it ;)
I just had to click on "Find pattern" on the memory dump window and I found the same function as Olly !